# Unexpected behavior of Python multithreading in AWS EC2 instance [Updated]

Tags: python, multithreading, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, python-multithreading

This is a more detailed version of the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68248489/unexpected-behavior-of-python-multithreading-in-aws-ec2-instance)

Please help me understand why I am getting different results when I run my project on local machine and on AWS EC2 instance.

I am using python multithreading to achieve concurrency and parallelism in my Django web app. I can create a new workflow when a user requests one from the front end. There can be multiple workflows running together in the background, each using its own thread.

**views.py**

```
def request_for_new_workflow(request):
    ...
    thread_id = unique_id_for_this_request
    thread_obj = threading.Thread(target=handler.some_function, name=str(thread_id), args=my_args)
    handler.allThreads[thread_id] = {}
    handler.allThreads[thread_id]['object'] = thread_obj
    handler.allThreads[thread_id]['isAllowed'] = True
    ...
    return HttpResponse("New Workflow Started", status=200)

def stop_workflow(request):
    thread_id = request.POST.get('id')                       
    if thread_id in handler.allThreads:                     <-------------------- Error Here
        handler.allThreads['create-event-workflow-'+id]['isAllowed'] = False
    return HttpResponse("Workflow Stopped", status=200)
```

**handler.py** contains many functions which will be called directly from view (only one from each request). Each function can take hours to complete depending upon the args passed. (most of the time is consumed by time.sleep). All functions here are I/O intensive and not CPU intensive.
Also, the `allThreads` dictionary, which maintains data about any thread is present in this file.

```
allThreads = {}
# Structure of allThreads when it contains workflows:
# allThreads = {
#    'unique_id' : {
#                    'object' : Thread_Object,
#                    'isAllowed' : Boolean
#                  },
#    ...
# }

def some_function_1(args):  # can run for hours (in background) after getting a request from user
    ... 
    while(conditions): # can run for a few 100 times
        # do I/O intensive tasks (usually takes a few seconds)
        time.sleep(anywhere between a few seconds to few minutes)
    ...
    # make changes to DB
```

**Error** in `if thread_id in handler.allThreads:` as handler.allThreads is either empty, or it contains incomplete list of workflows. The workflows randomly come and go from  `handler.allThreads`.

I could not understand why this is happening. The only difference is the configuration of both machines (local and AWS server).

Local Machine config - CPU- 8th-gen i5-8250U, RAM- 8GB, Success Ratio: ~100%

Server config 1 - (t2.small) - vCPU-1, RAM-2GB, Success Ratio: ~10%

Server config 2 - (c5a.xlarge) - vCPU-4, RAM-8GB, Success Ratio: ~80%

**Please help me understand the problem and how can I resolve this?? Which configuration/server would you recommend?
Any help is appreciated..Thank you in advance**

Comment: It's difficult to speculate. You haven't even proven operating system that you use on local and at aws, python versions, django versions. There is also no example how  could anyone reproduce the issue to try help you.

Comment: If you're not going to edit the previous iteration, please delete it. Or delete this and edit that one.

Comment: @Marcin OS - Windows 10 64bit (local), Ubuntu (AWS), Django 3.2.4 on both Local and AWS, Python Version - 3.9 and 3.6 (local-tried on both),  3.6 (AWS). Please let me know if you need anything more. Thanks

Comment: @jonrsharpe I will delete the older post.